# HttpWebRequest stream write never completes

Tags: c#, .net, stream, httpwebrequest

I'm posting a file with `HttpWebRequest`, along with a header and footer. The header (ca. 0.5K) and the actual file seem to write fine, but with large files (ca. 15MB), the footer (which is like 29 bytes) never seems to write.

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
    requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.Min(4096L, fileSize)];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) {
        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    // next line never completes                        
    requestStream.Write(postFooterBytes, 0, postFooterBytes.Length);

    // code below is never reached
    Console.WriteLine("Why do I never see this message in the console?");
}
```

Any thoughts?

**ETA:** Tried flushing the stream before the last `Write()`, on the off chance it would help, but to no effect.

**Edited again:** Added `using()` to clarify that I'm not a *complete* idiot. Note also BTW that this is inside *another* `using()` block for `fileStream`.

Comment: Obvious point, but you're sure that the footer is emitted when you're *not* using HttpWebRequest, right? (e.g. from a browser or wget)

Comment: @harpo I'm not sure I understand. It's me emitting the footer.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looping forever on the read?

Comment: The Console.WriteLine() call works if you put that before the requestStream.Write() call?

Comment: Just to clarify: the program is hanging in that last write, and not throwing an exception? Also, what happens if you just don't write the footer?

Comment: If I don't write the footer, it hangs on whatever the last write call is. (Actually, if I *just* don't write it, I get an exception saying I didn't write the full length before closing the stream. But if I adjust the contentLength and then don't write it, it hangs on the last previous call.) I think it's a buffering issue -- see answer below re: AllowWriteStreamBuffering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: Turned off `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` on the `HttpWebRequest`. Looks like when it's on, whatever `Write()` call writes the last byte, it doesn't return till the internal buffer's cleared. So the last `Write()` was eventually competing, just not till I ran out of patience.

And since what I was originally trying to do was determine progress, turning off buffering makes things clearer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A common problem is forgetting closing the request stream. One of the symptoms you'll see is that the request is never made. It's quite likely that the write really is completing, but since you didn't close the request stream, the call to `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` appears not to be executed.

Try the following and see if it makes a difference:

```
using (var requestStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    // write to the request stream here
}
// Now try to get the response.
```

Another possible issue is the size of the data. First, are you sure that the server can handle a 15 MB upload? Secondly, if you're doing this on a slow connection, 15 MB can take a while to send. I have what's considered a "fast" upstream connection at 1.5 megabits/sec. That's, at best, 0.15 megabytes per second. Sending 15 megabytes will take over a minute and a half.

One other possibility is that the request is timing out. You want to look into the `HttpWebRequest.Timeout` and `ReadWriteTimeout` properties.

Comment: The code snippet above is inside a `using()` block, and it's not `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` that isn't executed, it's any code below the last write -- e.g., a `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: @David: okay. See my note about size.

Comment: So is the expected behavior that it appears to write everything quickly, but then hangs on the last write call while it waits for it to 'really' be written? Because this behavior is consistent over a variation of several hundred K -- the file data loop completes, then the footer hangs.

Comment: @David: Writing everything quickly wouldn't surprise me, as it could all go to an internal buffer and then be trickled out to the server. Why the footer write would hang is a mystery. I suppose if the post footer was huge, that could cause a problem, but you said it's very small. And even if it's timing out, I would expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I think you were on the right track. I turned off `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` and (1) the file writing goes much more slowly, while (2) the footer completes just fine. Apparently writing the last byte doesn't return till the internal buffer's flushed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are building your request, your content length should include the headers as well, make sure its not just set to the file length.
The other thing you may try is to call `.Flush()` on the stream when all is said and done.
I'm not sure of the implication of closing the stream for the HttpClient as Jim suggests, it may work, it may make it worse.

Does using `System.Net.WebClient` not offer enough flexibility for you? Theres a nice `UploadFile()` method you can use.

Comment: The content length already takes the header and footer into account, but thanks. I tried adding a `Flush()` after the last `Write()`, but it's never reached.

Comment: Normally in managed code, lines don't just become 'unreachable' without an exception or something thrown. Can you try and put a breakpoint on your last write and see what happens after that line is executed? Are you ever calling `.GetResponse()` from your `HttpWebRequest` object?